# trying to write bash script that sends email with output from two variables ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The problem I am having is that the action I am looking for is for sendemail to send myself an email that contains both `w` output from the ssh user and output from doing an `lsof -u` on $SSH_USER to see what open files they have.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This line looks for the string "pts/" in the output of `w`, then strips out the owner information and passes it to SSH_USER

SSH_USER="$(w | grep "pts/" | cut -d" " -f1 | awk 'NR < 2')";
SSH_USERS="$(w)"

if w  | grep -q "pts/"; then
  echo "someone logged-in via ssh" && sendemail -f "xxx.notify@gmail.com" -u "someone has logged-in via ssh " -t "my.email@gmail.com" -s "smtp.gmail.com:587" -m "$SSH_USERS \n lsof -u "$SSH_USER"" -o tls=yes -xu "xxx.notify@gmail.com" -xp 'my_notify.email.pw'
else
  echo "nobody logged-in via ssh"
fi
```

Note that the -m option is where the body of the email goes, and I am filling it with two variables. One is the output of `w` and the other is the ouput of an `lsof -u $SSH_USER`, which in this case should expand out to `lsof -u robert`.

Here is the output of `w`:

```
23:46:23 up  3:41,  3 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.44, 0.50
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
robert   :0       :0               20:07   ?xdm?   6:10   0.01s /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-se
robert   pts/1    10.0.0.3         22:56   50:04   0.04s  0.04s -bash
robert   pts/4    10.0.0.3         23:10   36:16   0.04s  0.04s -bash
```

Here is the email I am getting:

```
23:40:31 up  3:35,  3 users,  load average: 0.60, 0.60, 0.56
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
robert   :0       :0               20:07   ?xdm?   6:05   0.01s /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
robert   pts/1    10.0.0.3         22:56   44:12   0.04s  0.04s -bash
robert   pts/4    10.0.0.3         23:10   30:24   0.04s  0.04s -bash 
 lsof -u robert
```

You can see at the bottom of the email it says `lsof -u robert` so it expands the variable correctly - but it just echos it, instead of displaying the output of the command.

There must be something I am doing wrong in the `-m "$SSH_USERS \n lsof -u "$SSH_USER""` part of the script - what could be the reason that it's only sending me the output from the first half of the message? How to get that `lsof -u $SSH_USER` to actually run and provide output rather than just echo itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Bash command substitution in the same manner as you have done earlier in the script.

Change:

```
-m "$SSH_USERS \n lsof -u "$SSH_USER""
```

to

```
-m "$SSH_USERS \n $(lsof -u "$SSH_USER")"
```

This will actually run the `lsof` command that you're looking for.

It's also worth noting that double quotes do not nest, they act like a toggle, som in the original version, you quote `"$SSH_USERS \n lsof -u "` while $SSH_USER is unquoted, then the `""` at the end doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually, I screwed up - I was editing a commented out command (doh!). I edited the right command and now the only error I am getting is `ssh-login: line 19: /usr/bin/sendemail: Argument list too long`. So, I am guessing your command works - it's just expanding to such a  message length with the `lsof` output that it's too long for the outgoing email. I will try to grep it down a bit and try again.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I changed the command to `-m "$SSH_USERS \n $(lsof -u "$SSH_USER" | grep bash)"` and now I get the out put from `w` and the output of `lsof -u robert | grep bash` in the same email notification - thank you for your help!